Connect to firebase DB
im trying to developt a simple Website in React to know the games that are launched in a month, for that i want to store that data on a firebase db(handmade) and read it.
But in the first trys, im not getting connection.
I have this to try
Firebase Data
but im getting:
Error console
First i tried throught a thunk, that im dont know how to make it work, and now im trying directly through the component "Game.jsx". Im a bit lost and searching isnt giving a lot of info
This is the project, https://github.com/saulOMgit/CalendarioVideojuegos, any clues?

First go to your firestore and change rules



 rules_version = '2';
 service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}



